# How to exclude total span tag i.e i want only text in p tag inside of this p tag span tag should be excluded

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

[image]

I need text inside the p tag excluding the span tag by using scrapy code.

I'm attaching the html path in the image please find it and help me.

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="post-55812"]/div/p').not(span::text).extract()
```

Error:

```
  File "<console>", line 1
    response.xpath('//*[@id="post-55812"]/div/p').not(span::text).extract()[1:11]))
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
response.css('#post-55812 > div > p:not(span)').extract()
```

Comment: ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //*[@id="post-55812"]/div/p/[not(self::span)]                                                                                                      sorry this is the error that when run above one @Umair

Comment: response.css('#post-55812 > div > p:not(span)').extract()[1]
u'<p>1. Which is the correct operator for power(x<sup>y</sup>)?<br>\na) X^y<br>\nb) X**y<br>\nc) X^^y<br>\nd) None of the mentioned<br>\n<span class="collapseomatic " id="id2959" tabindex="" title="View Answer">View Answer</span></p>'                                                                                                     still the span tag was there @Umair

Comment: You're just blurting out markup. What does that do? How does it answer the question? Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer